# Reading cookies associated with cross-site resources in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, formik

I have a react application which makes use of `Formik` to handle the forms on the website. Currently when I open the website I recieve the following warning:

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at `<URL>` was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at `<URL>` and `<URL>`.

The input `<Formik.Field>` gets filled with the data stored in the cookies but it seems that `Formik` itself does not notice, that the value changed. When I try to read those cookies using `cookies-js`I can only see the cookies from the current domain.

```js
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

export const LoginComponent = () => {
    let formikProps

    console.log(Cookies.get()) // only prints cookies from the current domain
    // ....
```

I need to take notice when the input value changes because I want to add a styleclass to that element in this case. Any suggestions?

greetings

Comment: Can you provide more information here? The console warning you're receiving says that a "future release of Chrome" will block these cookies, i.e. it is not currently blocking them. Is the warning referencing a domain that you control or is it referencing a third-party domain? The cookies you are mentioning for filling the form - do you set them or does a third-party set them?